# SQL 2008 installation on SSD

Tags: installation, ssd, sql-server-2008

Can SQL 2008 Developer be installed on an SSD ExpressCard? The device is a Transcend 32GB ExpressCard.

I'm getting the following error:

```
The path E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\ is not on a specified drive Type.
```

I suppose it's because the device is "removable" and not "fixed", but I'm thinking there is probably some way around this.

Comment: It might be helpful if you mention the specific make and model of the SSD.

Comment: Technically, every drive is "removable". I'm sure even Mac drives can be removed somehow.

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft's [hardware and software requirements for installing SQL Server 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506%28SQL.100%29.aspx):

> SQL Server Setup will block
>   installations on read-only or
>   compressed drives.

Could it be that your drive is compressed?

Comment: I made sure compression was off since my entire goal is to speed things up.